# Send checkbox value to rails model field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I would like to send the value of my checkbox (true/false) to my rails model field (:taxable) on the state change of that button.

So far I have this, but I am not sure where to go from here

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.taxable').on('change', function(event) {
    var checkbox = $(event.target);
    var isChecked = $(checkbox).is(':checked');
    /* */
  });
});
</script>


<%= f.input :taxable, :as => :boolean, hint: "Is order taxable?",:id => 'taxable', :class => "taxable", :remote => true %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.taxable').on('change', function(event) {
    var checkbox = $(event.target);
    var isChecked = $(checkbox).is(':checked');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/url",
      data: { params: { taxable: isChecked } },
      success:(data) {
        alert(data)
        return true;
},
      error:(data) {
        return false
}
    })
    /* */
  });
});
</script>


<%= f.input :taxable, :as => :boolean, hint: "Is order taxable?",:id => 'taxable', :class => "taxable", :remote => true %>
```

Comment: Submit as a AJAX request to URL